# Compiling Pythonika on MacOS

Tags: c++, python, wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I'm compiling [Pythonika](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6622/) on Snow Leopard and the errors I get suggest that I'm missing some standard flag, any idea what's missing? Another [post](http://www.tangentspace.net/cz/archives/2010/02/cvxopt-pythonika-convex-optimization-from-mathematica/) suggests I need -lrt flag, but that's not available on MacOS

```
cc -I/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/CompilerAdditions -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/ Pythonika.o Pythonikatm.o -L/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/CompilerAdditions -lMLi3 -F/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/ -framework Python -o Pythonika
Undefined symbols:
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::reserve(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      _mlipinterfacecontainer_get_domain_names in libMLi3.a(mlipinterface.c.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldConnectServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::AddInterfaceQualifier(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::LoadIPFromString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLObjectBrokers::MLUnixNameBrokerCore::MLUnixNameBrokerCore(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformobjectbrokers.cpp.o)
  "_kCFUserNotificationAlternateButtonTitleKey", referenced from:
      _MLRequest_darwin in libMLi3.a(mlosx.c.o)
      _MLConfirm_darwin in libMLi3.a(mlosx.c.o)
  "std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_istringstream(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::AddPort(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::MLIPAddress(char const*, char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::MLIPAddress(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLDeviceParameters::MLDeviceParameters(char*)in libMLi3.a(mldevices.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLDeviceParameters::MLDeviceParameters(char*)in libMLi3.a(mldevices.cpp.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _mlfile_get_exe_name_from_command in libMLi3.a(mlfileops.c.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::LoadIPFromString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::LoadIPFromString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldConnectServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformobjectbrokers.cpp.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
      MLNetwork::MLInitializeIPAddressModule()      in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::LoadIPFromString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLIPAddress::LoadIPFromString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLExceptions::MLException::MLException(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<int> >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<int> >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<int> >::operator[](int const&)in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<int> >::MLHashTable()in libMLi3.a(mlipaddress.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetPreferredInterface()      in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetPreferredInterface_c_str()      in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetInterfaceFromHostname(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetInterfaceFromHostname(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetInterfaceFromAddress(MLNetwork::MLIPAddress const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetInterfaceFromAddress_c_str(MLNetwork::MLIPAddress const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::AddInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6HostnameFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6HostnameFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6HostnameFromInterface(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4HostnameFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4HostnameFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4HostnameFromInterface(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6AddressFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6AddressFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4AddressFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4AddressFromInterface(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6AddressFromHostname(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV6AddressFromHostname(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4AddressFromHostname(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLNetwork::MLInterfaceContainer::GetIPV4AddressFromHostname(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLExceptions::MLException::MLException(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::push_front(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      void MLLists::exch<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLExceptions::MLException::MLException(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::MLHashTable()in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::MLHashTable()in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::operator[](std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::MLHashTable(MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::MLHashTable(MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<MLNetwork::MLIPAddress, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLIPAddressHashFunction>::MLHashTable()in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<MLNetwork::MLIPAddress, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLIPAddressHashFunction>::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<MLNetwork::MLIPAddress, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLIPAddressHashFunction>::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<MLNetwork::MLIPAddress, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLIPAddressHashFunction>::operator[](MLNetwork::MLIPAddress const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<MLNetwork::MLIPAddress, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLIPAddressHashFunction>::MLHashTable(MLHashTables::MLHashTable<MLNetwork::MLIPAddress, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLIPAddressHashFunction> const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::MLList()in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLInterface, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::MLHashTable()in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLInterface, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLInterface, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::resize(unsigned long)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLInterface, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::MLHashTable(MLHashTables::MLHashTable<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, MLNetwork::MLInterface, MLHashTables::MLGenericHashFunction<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::push_back(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::sort()in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::MLList(MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLLists::MLList<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insert(MLLists::MLListNode_Iterator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)in libMLi3.a(mlinterface.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldConnectServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::DetermineLocalHostnameAndProtocol()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::GetHostname()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::GetHostname()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::GetHostname()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::CreateServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::CreateServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::CreateClient()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldCreateServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldCreateServer()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::OldCreateClient()      in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(char*, MLDevices::MLTCPIPWorld*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice()in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice::MLTCPIPDevice(MLDevices::MLTCPIPDevice const&)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLExceptions::MLException::MLException(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mltcpip.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::makeIPCName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::makeIPCName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::DestroyName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::DestroyName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::DestroyName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::NameValidQ(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLSemaphoreConditionHelper::MLSemaphoreConditionHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode, void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLSemaphoreConditionHelper::MLSemaphoreConditionHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode, void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLFifoConditionHelper::MLFifoConditionHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode, void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLFifoConditionHelper::MLFifoConditionHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode, void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLFileLockingMutexHelper::MLFileLockingMutexHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLFileLockingMutexHelper::MLFileLockingMutexHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLFileLockingMutexHelper::MLFileLockingMutexHelper(void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLFileLockingMutexHelper::MLFileLockingMutexHelper(void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper(void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper::MLSemaphoreMutexHelper(void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle()in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle const&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(char const*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(char const*, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixMutexHandle::MLUnixMutexHandle(void*)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixCondition::MLUnixCondition()in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixCondition::MLUnixCondition(MLThreads::MLUnixCondition&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixCondition::MLUnixCondition(MLThreads::MLUnixCondition const&)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
      MLThreads::MLUnixCondition::MLUnixCondition(MLThreads::MLUnixCondition&, MLThreads::_mlcondreset, MLThreads::_mlsyncmode)in libMLi3.a(mlplatformthreads.cpp.o)
```

Comment: The messages you posted look like `C++`. I've changed the `C` tag accordingly

Comment: Check out this link http://code.google.com/p/pythonika/downloads/detail?name=Pythonika-2.6&can=2&q= I am not sure about the versions.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work, I suspect it was 32-executable, Mathematica 8.0 for MacOS is 64-bit. Recompilation worked though

Comment: Did you try to use CreateExecutable function from CCompilerDriver package ?

Comment: I didn't modify the package, was just trying to compile it. I got it working though -- http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2011/03/semidefinite-programming-in-mathematica.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you might need the following linker flags:

-lstdc++ -framework CoreFoundation

Comment: just adding `-framework CoreFoundation` was sufficient, thanks